# Checking if any string element of the column is matching with other column string list in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

df

```
     CAR1                        CAR2
['ford','hyundai']         ['ford','hyundai']
['ford','hyundai']         ['hyundai','nissan']
['ford','hyundai']         ['bmw', 'audi']
```

Expected output :

```
 CAR1                        CAR2                   Flag
['ford','hyundai']         ['ford','hyundai']        1
['ford','hyundai']         ['hyundai','nissan']      1
['ford','hyundai']         ['bmw', 'audi']           0
```

Raise flag 1 in case of any elements/string from CAR1 matches with CAR2, else raise flag 0

My try is:

```
df[[x in y for x,y in zip(df['CAR1'], df['CAR2'])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: first convert columns to lists:

```
import ast

cols = ['CAR1','CAR2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Use `set.intersection` in list comprehension with convert to boolean and integers for `True,False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
df['Flag'] = [int(bool(set(x).intersection(y))) for x,y in zip(df['CAR1'], df['CAR2'])]
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['Flag'] = [1 if set(x).intersection(y) else 0 for x,y in zip(df['CAR1'], df['CAR2'])]

print (df)
              CAR1               CAR2  Flag
0  [ford, hyundai]    [ford, hyundai]     1
1  [ford, hyundai]  [hyundai, nissan]     1
2  [ford, hyundai]        [bmw, audi]     0
```

Comment: using the above script I am getting flag 1 for even 3rd row, what I am doing wrong ? @jezrael

Comment: @AB14 - added `EDIT` to answer, seems in columns are strings, not lists.

Comment: @jezrael there wasn't an issue with accepting my answer either, not sure why you think yours is better ;)

Comment: @jezrael you have been the saviour sir, it was very helpful as always ! But using literal_val I am getting ValueError: malformed node or string. Kindly suggest ? I have accepted the answer, dont know why it is showing not accepted !

Comment: @AB14 you can only accept one answer, not two. And jezrael doesn't like not being the accepted answer

Comment: @mozway Got it sir ! my bad, beg you sorry :(

Comment: @AB14 - Are data condfidental? Because it seems data related issue, in real data working well.

Comment: Got it @jezrael

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org//3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) operations in a list comprehension ([`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org//3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) returns False if the sets overlap, which is inverted and converted to integer with `1-x`):

```
df['Flag'] = [1-set(s1).isdisjoint(s2) for s1, s2 in zip(df['CAR1'], df['CAR2'])]
```

*NB. `isdisjoint` is quite fast as it doesn't require to read the full sets, is returns False as soon as a common item is found.*

Output:

```
              CAR1               CAR2  Flag
0  [ford, hyundai]    [ford, hyundai]     1
1  [ford, hyundai]  [hyundai, nissan]     1
2  [ford, hyundai]        [bmw, audi]     0
```

##### from strings

```
from ast import literal_eval

df['Flag'] = [1-set(s1).isdisjoint(s2) for s1, s2 in
               zip(df['CAR1'].apply(literal_eval),
                   df['CAR2'].apply(literal_eval))]
```

Comment: I am getting flag1 for all the rows ! Could you suggest why its happening ?

Comment: @AB14 do you have strings or real lists? If strings convert first to lists

Comment: While using the literal_eval I am getting ValueError: malformed node or string @mozway

Comment: @AB14 then the issue is different than the provided example, you should probably open a new question